# AWS Lambda Adding Layer for Open Telemetry : arn:aws:lambda:ap-southeast-2:901920570463:layer:aws-otel-python-x86_64-ver-1-17-0:1

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, open-telemetry, otel

Getting error

[image: arn:aws:iam::myaccountid:root is not authorized to perform:lambda GetLayerVersion on resource arn:aws:lambda:ap-southeast-2:901920570463:layer:aws-otel-python-x86_64-ver-1-17-0:1]

while adding the Open Telemetry Layer for my python Lambda function. I added all IAM permissions required:

[image: GetLayerVersion Permissions]

Also tried with adding all the permissions for Lambda, added another IAM user with all permissions, but it's not working. I am using personal AWS free tier account and my requirement is to configure open telemetry to send telemetry data to Grafana.

Docs referred:

- https://opentelemetry.io/docs/faas/lambda-manual-instrument/
- https://aws-otel.github.io/docs/getting-started/lambda/lambda-python
- https://github.com/theam/aws-lambda-haskell-runtime/issues/1
- https://www.tecracer.com/blog/2022/12/spy/adot

Comment: Given that you use ADOT can you please follow our official docs (https://aws-otel.github.io/docs/getting-started/lambda/lambda-python) and see if you arrive at the same error?

Comment: This is the one I first tried, missed to add the link above. I am getting same error while specify arn in layers